# Pylab: map labels to colors

Tags: python, scipy, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I'm just starting with the `scipy` stack. I'm using the iris dataset, in a CSV version. I can load it just fine using:

```
iris=numpy.recfromcsv("iris.csv")
```

and plot it:

```
pylab.scatter(iris.field(0), iris.field(1))
pylab.show()
```

Now I'd like to also plot the classes, which are stored in `iris.field(4)`:

```
chararray(['setosa', ...], dtype='|S10')
```

What is an elegant way to map these strings to colors for plotting? `scatter(iris.field(0), iris.field(1), c=iris.field(4))` does not work (from the docs it expect float values or a colormap). I havn't found an elegant way of automatically generating a color map.

```
cols = {"versicolor": "blue", "virginica": "green", "setosa": "red"}
scatter(iris.field(0), iris.field(1), c=map(lambda x:cols[x], iris.field(4)))
```

does approximately what I want, but I don't like the manual color specification too much.

***Edit***: slightly more elegant version of the last line:

```
scatter(iris.field(0), iris.field(1), c=map(cols.get, iris.field(4)))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For whatever it's worth, you'd typically do something more like this in that case:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

iris = np.recfromcsv('iris.csv')
names = set(iris['class'])

x,y = iris['sepal_length'],  iris['sepal_width']

for name in names:
    cond = iris['class'] == name
    plt.plot(x[cond], y[cond], linestyle='none', marker='o', label=name)

plt.legend(numpoints=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

There's nothing wrong with what @Yann suggested, but `scatter` is better suited for continuous data.

It's easier to rely on the axes color cycle and just call plot multiple times (you also get separate artists instead of a collection, which is a good thing for discrete data such as this).

By default, the color cycle for an axes is: blue, green, red, cyan, magenta, yellow, black.

After 7 calls to `plot`, it will cycle back over those colors, so if you have more items, you'll need to [set it manually](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/api/color_cycle.html) (or just specify the color in each call to `plot` using an interpolated colorbar similar to what @Yann suggested above).

Comment: Thank you. I saw the option of multi-plotting, but I wasn't yet aware of the elegant condition trick you used here (+1). I have to disagree about `scatter`. To my understanding it is exactly meant for this kind of plots, where the points are independent and not connected (which you work around by setting `linestyle="none"`)

Comment: The `plot` vs `scatter` point is an unfortunate and common misconception.  Use `plot` to plot points, and only use `scatter` to plot things when you need to continuously vary the size and/or color of the markers based on a 3rd or 4th variable.  `scatter` returns a collection that is much harder to manage.  `plot` _really is_ intended to plot disconnected points, the default just happens to be a line.  If you want a more concise call, `plt.plot(x, y, 'o')` will do the same thing as `plt.plot(x, y, linestyle='none', marker='o')`.

Comment: Thank you. I use `np.unique(iris.field(4))` (since my CSV doesn't have a colum label row). But other than that I'm now essentially using your code. I really like the condition trick.

Comment: How can I reproduce this with sklearn.datasets.load_iris()? I am not sure what numpy.recfromcsv() returns.

Answer (score 5):

Whether a way is elegant or not is somewhat subjective. I personally find your approaches better then the 'matplotlib' way. From matplotlib's [color](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/colors_api.html#module-matplotlib.colors) module:

> Colormapping typically involves two steps: a data array is first
>   mapped onto the range 0-1 using an instance of Normalize or of a
>   subclass; then this number in the 0-1 range is mapped to a color using
>   an instance of a subclass of Colormap.

What I take from this in regards to your problem is that you need a subclass of `Normalize` that takes strings and maps them to 0-1.

Here's an example that inherits from `Normalize` to make a subclass `TextNorm`, which is used to convert a string to a value from 0 to 1. This normalization is used to get a corresponding color.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
import numpy as np
from numpy import ma

class TextNorm(Normalize):
    '''Map a list of text values to the float range 0-1'''

    def __init__(self, textvals, clip=False):
        self.clip = clip
        # if you want, clean text here, for duplicate, sorting, etc
        ltextvals = set(textvals)
        self.N = len(ltextvals)
        self.textmap = dict(
            [(text, float(i)/(self.N-1)) for i, text in enumerate(ltextvals)])
        self.vmin = 0
        self.vmax = 1

    def __call__(self, x, clip=None):
        #Normally this would have a lot more to do with masking
        ret = ma.asarray([self.textmap.get(xkey, -1) for xkey in x])
        return ret

    def inverse(self, value):
        return ValueError("TextNorm is not invertible")

iris = np.recfromcsv("iris.csv")
norm = TextNorm(iris.field(4))

plt.scatter(iris.field(0), iris.field(1), c=norm(iris.field(4)), cmap='RdYlGn')
plt.savefig('textvals.png')
plt.show()
```

This produces:

[image]

I chose the 'RdYlGn' color map so that it was easy to distinguish between the three types of points. I did not include the `clip` feature as part of `__call__`, though it's possible with a few modifications.

Traditionally you can test the normalization of the `scatter` method using the `norm` keyword, but `scatter` tests the `c` keyword to see if it stores strings, and if it does, then it assumes you are passing in colors as their string values, e.g. 'Red', 'Blue', etc. So calling `plt.scatter(iris.field(0), iris.field(1), c=iris.field(4), cmap='RdYlGn', norm=norm)` fails. Instead I just use the `TextNorm` and "operate" on the `iris.field(4)` to return an array of values ranging from 0 to 1.

Note that a value of -1 is returned for a sting not in the list `textvals`. This is where masking would come in handy.

Comment: Since I just did the same in `R` (trying to make an overview of the tools), I was wondering whether there is an equivalent of `unclass` in `scipy`.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I'm not sure what you're asking in your comment. How would you use `unclass` and what would you use it on.

Comment: Well, `unclass` essentially enumerates the distinct labels. So each row is one of `1`..`3` for the iris dataset (R indexes start at 1).
And then you can use this to index into a list of distinct colors. Kind of a `cls = list(numpy.unique(iris.field(4)))`; `cols=["red", "green", "blue"]` and `scatter(..., c=map(lamda x:cols[cls.index(x)], iris.field(4)))`

Comment: As seen from the other answer, a similar effect can be achieved by filtering the data set by each label and plotting them separately with `plot` instead of `scatter`.